# Warn users when using the Tables feature in question formatting tool

Tags: feature-request, questions, minimal-reproducible-example, performance

Lately I observe that more and more new users use the *Tables* feature in the [question formatting tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Ref.: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503666/r-studio-error-in-regularizetimestamps-defaulttrain-time-stamps-must-occur-a), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505782/creating-a-text-data-frame-from-multiple-xml-files), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503666/r-studio-error-in-regularizetimestamps-defaulttrain-time-stamps-must-occur-a), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65511020/6574038).

Has it been specifically suggested anywhere recently?  May be a coincidental accumulation, but I don't recall observing this before.

Firstly, it is very cumbersome and backward for the user to create such tables, and secondly, it has many disadvantages compared to `dput` in R and other more suitable methods of sharing data, because it fails to scope all the important features of the data shared. This can lead to frustration of the askers, because they are requested to share the data properly and they don't know why, get no or bad answers, or even might get downvoted or closed. The same applies to the answerers, who are annoyed that they do not have proper data available to reproduce an issue.

**My spontaneous suggestion:**

Could there be a small pop-up or something implemented that appears when clicking feature button with a text like the following?

> ***Note: Using the Tables feature to share data may result in important data characteristics not being captured, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)***

I'm not sure how to make this suitable for all tags, but I think at least in the R tag it could help improve workflow significantly.

Comment: I would support making this available for specific tags. I know some people active in [sql] have expressed similar misgivings about the feature. But for, say, [javascript], it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Seems like this would be a better link if it can be tag specific as apparently the R community has a specific consensus on how to share data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: For SQL it is easy enough to generate DDL from these tables using the "text to DDL" feature in SQL Fiddle (as long as the Q isn't asking about some behaviour that depends on specific datatypes not shown to us)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357335/266284