# Discouraging questioners from posting data in table form for questions on R/SQL

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tables

Questions based on [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) are much easier to answer if the questioner posts a small example of their data using a function such as `dput`, so that the answerer can paste the data quickly into their own console. There is a good explanation of why this is necessary [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). New users often post images of their data which makes it vastly more difficult to answer the question, along with other issues regarding searchability.

I have noticed now that many users post their data in the form of a formatted table, such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931471/boxplotting-count-data-with-continuous-variable-in-r). These tables aren't quite as bad as images, but they are still tricky to paste into your console and make answering the question somewhat annoying. Personally I will avoid any questions where the data is formatted like this.

I was wondering if there would be a way to discourage users to share their data in this format for particular questions (like in R)? Perhaps some kind of tooltip or note under the table tab which suggests it's not a good way to share data?

EDIT: User Larnu points out this applies to questions regarding SQL as well.

EDIT 2: A couple of users seems to have confused exactly why this is an issue. It is not because I have impossibly high standards for how people should format their posts. It is because it is a) potentially error prone and b) time consuming to read in the data from a table. Perhaps unlike questions regarding other languages, it is **crucial** to have a minimally reproducible example of a dataset in R.

To quote a comment by Chris Schaller:

> .. you have to somehow provide that exact data.frame to R, which
> typically means manually typing out that object (e.g. placing double
> quotes around strings, commas between values, instantiating the
> object) and even then you're kinda left guessing as to the class of
> the object - for example, in the OP's example question, it could be a
> tibble or a data.frame (or something else), but we're never really
> sure

Edit3: I just noticed that @KonradRudolph has helpfully pointed out in the comments that the function `clipr::read_clip_tbl()` very easily allows for the reading in of table presented in data form. I still think it's not ideal since I don't think it accounts for differences in types, but it is a lot easier than trying to copy and paste them directly.

Comment: You could write a "canned comment", like Peter did in that linked question, telling users how to properly provide the example data.

Comment: I, personally, don't think this just applies to R. The new tables are awful for SQL based questions too, as converting them to DML statements requires a lot of effort. A fixed width tabular `text` table, however, is far easier to deal with. The new table markdown is "nice" but it's not always useful unfortunately; sometimes to opposite.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357335/266284

Comment: @Larnu That might be worth pointing out in the editing FAQ as well. I can see someone posting a SQL question with their data in that format only to have someone edit it into the new markdown.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with markdown tables in SQL questions. If you copy/paste the table to a text editor, the columns are separated by tabs, which seems just as easy to replace as replacing a pipe symbol. Of course, it would be better if such questions would include DDL and DML *scripts*. But if the comparison is with pipe separated code-formatted tables, then I don't really see a difference in effort to turn it into a script.

Comment: I made a userscript to show a button when you hover over tables that lets you copy the table to a CSV format. It works great for me. Only reason I didn't publish it is because I'm a pretty average front-end dev, but if anyone wants to take it and make it better... https://gist.github.com/WiredUK/26bc458f7ec2d17ae5be8e03ce0c1011

Comment: I find that data posted as formatted tables is superior because it _enhances_ the ability to cut and paste into consoles and tool like SSMS and excel, so for SQL I disagree with this post and I want to encourage more users to use formatted tables. It is a deliberate and consitant standard, instead of all the other variants in code blocks. The key for me is that the tables cut'n'paste as tab delimited which is very versatile and even translates well into scripts and consoles.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller in R it's kinda annoying because to replicate the issue, you have to somehow provide that exact data.frame to R, which typically means manually typing out that object (e.g. placing double quotes around strings, commas between values, instantiating the object) and even then you're kinda left guessing as to the class of the object - for example, in the OP's example question, it could be a tibble or a data.frame (or something else), but we're never really sure.

Comment: @stevec I can't comment on R, but for since SQL was brought in it highlights a similar issue, having the data in a table still requires parsing work, you can rarely use it directly, but the table now provides a standard, the underlying syntax can vary a lot, but the formatted output is consistent, meaning once you have learned to use it, it saves a lot of time. It would be awesome if users posted questions with full DDL and DML scripts, but often a the questions asked indicate a level of knowledge that precludes OP from being able to provide this level of detail in the first place.

Comment: It's a while since I have done much answering but I think I remember correctly that the markdown tables paste OK into the "text to DDL" box on SQL Fiddle and so allow them to be converted to DDL that way.

Comment: Surely the real solution here is to have a flip-out button on the table allowing clipboard copying in various formats. The obvious ones being SQL, R and CSV, but perhaps there are others also

Comment: @Charlie "SQL" would probably require multiple flavours. To get multirow insert statements compatible with Oracle and SQL Server for example.

Comment: @MartinSmith Multi-row inserts are unnecessary, it's only going to be a few rows anyway. And as I said, we need multiple different options, and a flip-out menu can have as much as you want.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404125/6574038

Comment: If we have to discourage the most natural form of representing tabular data (a table) then the feature's a bug!

Comment: Does R not have a `read_clipboard` function similar to the functionality of `pandas.read_clipboard` (which works fine with those tables)? Looks like `datapasta` would achieve that. Still doesn't fully fix the problem of dtypes, but for those examples the sample table could be accompanied by code like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, that way you get the best of both worlds -- a table that clearly visualizes the problem for people seeking help and data to assist answerers in solving the problem.

Comment: I don't want to read the clipboard, I want to copy the whole thing and paste it in my console or a script file.

Comment: This applies 100% to Pandas, too. I see it constantly, and almost exclusively from new users.

Comment: @stevec Actually it’s trivial to import HTML tables into R.

Comment: @Larnu but that’s not caused by the markdown support for tables. There are tons of poor Java questions containing not a single line of Java code, but a JSON style dump (which has no syntactic support in markdown). People will write bad questions, with syntax support or without.

Comment: I never said it *was* caused by the markdown tables, @Holger ? I just said that the markdown tables don't help turn data posted into DML and DDL statements.

Comment: @Larnu the statement wasn’t that clear. So, it wasn’t better before the introduction of the markdown tables anyway?

Comment: I state *". A fixed width tabular `text` table, however, is far easier to deal with."* in my comment, @Holger . Apologies, but I'm not sure what about that isn't clear?

Comment: @Larnu ok, I was too much focused on the idea that people should post the DDL/DML statements in the first place. For me, as a Java answerer, neither text format is helpful, but I suppose, for SQL questions, it might also sometimes be important to know the actual column declarations, instead of having to guess them from a text dump of whatever form…

Comment: Yes, DDL and DML *is far* better than tabular `text`, @Holger , but again, I never said it wasn't. What I *did* state, however, is that tabular `text` data is *also* better than a markdown table for **sample** data. Tabular `text` can be fairly easily converted to a `VALUES` clause, for example, with some strong typing. This takes a bit more effort with tab delimited data, in my opinion. If every user supplied DDL and DML, I wouldn't have even made the comment; but far too many users still post images of Excel Spreadsheets instead...  They are *far* from useful most of the time.

Comment: @Larnu yes, I understood your comment (now). My previous comment was just trying to explain why I didn’t understand immediately. The fault was my narrow focus.

Comment: Related: [Could we add a tag-specific MRE page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366424/155423)

Answer (score 13):

More generally, there are optimal styles and suboptimal styles for presenting input for several different tags on Stack Exchange sites.

I don't program in R, but I do a lot of PHP and SQL tag pool swimming.  I find myself repeatedly asking people to format their:

- PHP input array/object data as the output from `var_export()`, because it provides an instantly testable format for volunteers.  We often get `print_r()` or `var_dump()` or `dd()` or `json_encode()`ed data.  `json_encode()`ed data is probably second best, but then if there is no coding attempt, then volunteers will need to make an arbitrary decision about decoding the data as an array or an object.
- SQL table schemas as table dumps/exports (for the same reason)
- JavaScript input as JSON

This persistent commenting to request higher quality formats does not scale, is tiresome, and wastes the time that I could be using <s>hammering duplicates</s> answering questions.

I am sure folks that are [SMEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert) in other tags will know the best syntax for fellow volunteers.  This is information that serves all users involved.  The OP gets faster answers with a higher possibility of correctness and answerers get ready-made data to experiment with and to fuel their online demonstrations.

I think it is appropriate to add something to language tag descriptions which recommends how to provide [[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)] data and how to express their desired output in an optimal fashion.

This way the community knows the difference between the "good" (instantly usable data), the "bad" (indirectly available data), and the "ugly" (screenshots).

This is not a problem unique to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This seems like a tooling problem. StackOverflow could build a question form with more structured input boxes, for input, code, output/error, expected output, etc. It could request tabular data to come in a machine readable form (DML, etc.), making it available to people who want to run the code, while still rendering it in a nice readable table for those just reading the question.

Comment: There are "machine readable forms" that are binary, and so can't be included in a question without requiring some sort of decoding, like base64.  I've often thought of the idea of being able to add an attachment to your question.  That would solve the problem trivially for reproducibility purposes.  Of course, it would be completely unhelpful for human readability of the question, but maybe the use of an attachment feature would require that a text "thumbnail" be supplied as well.

Comment: [Could we add a tag-specific MRE page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366424/155423)

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps in the medium term there can be a Stack Overflow feature that copies these tables in a format that is readable by most languages, for example [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)? I'm thinking about a button that either shows and highlights the corresponding code in a popup, or that directly copies the CSV code ready for pasting into whatever application.

This would combine both the nice readability of tables, and allow them to be exported at low effort for usage in the code.

Comment: That's why I wrote my own [userscript](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406525/discouraging-questioners-from-posting-data-in-table-form-for-questions-on-r-sql?cb=1#comment835228_406525)

Answer (score 8):

In SQL, users should ideally provide data as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)/[DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements and not as tables/images.

There are various issues with tabular data that makes it more difficult to answer including:

1. The answerer has to parse the tabular data and convert it to DDL/DML statements; this increases the burden on the answer and makes it less likely that you will get an answer (particularly if your minimal example has multiple tables or uses more esoteric functionality).
2. If your tabular data contains date or number columns and your actual DDL statements are storing them as, for example, strings then we cannot see that from the data. Replicating the problem may be impossible without replicating the identical DDL statements and that requires users to provide the DDL/DML statements and not just the data.
3. Sometimes the problem is not with the code the user is trying to debug; instead it is an issue with the data in their table that results from the DML statements used to insert the data. This can be due to character set issues or implicit casts (typically string to date) and, again, this requires the user's actual DML statements.

Comment: Very much agree.  I expect with an increase of DDL/DML statements in sql questions would come a decrease in "try this, it might work" answers.

Comment: I would suggest the asker do both, then. From the perspective of someone coming by in the future and trying to figure out whether a question also solves their problem, a table is much easier to read and understand quickly

Comment: How can this be made practical? E.g., what are some tools for doing this?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Write a Minimal Representative Example that it demonstrates your SQL problem in a self-contained environment (if you can't create a new one locally then you can use something like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)) and then copy-paste everything from that self-contained environment into your question (and then, if you used one, also include a link to the fiddle).

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with the premise.

Yes, `dput` *can* be useful. But (finally!) having table formatting helps show, well, a *formatted* table: humans simply read such data better than the output from `dput`. And your concern about reproducibility is based on an error: importing such data into R isn’t particularly hard. For instance, you could use the `read_clip_tbl` function from the ‘clipr’ package. Personally I tend not to bother — I’ve got a shortcut function which does the equivalent of `read_clip`, and pass that to the `text` argument of `read.table` (which works well with tables copied from a website).

Of course I can’t force you to use the mechanisms. But that’s *on you*, not on the person who provides properly formatted data with their reproducible example.

The upshot is: we should *encourage* people to post properly-formatted tables, not discourage them. For non-tabular data (or where the exact data type is important), `dput` is still useful (and if the formatted table is insufficient feel free to ask the OP for a data dump). But `dput` should no longer be the default.

Comment: Just piggybacking this answer since I clicked into the question from it - why not have both the tabular representation *and* a way that makes it easier for readers to reproduce the problem? Tabular representations are great for readability... but only readability. So having tabular representations alone isn't ideal, but yeah we shouldn't outright discourage tables. We ought to have the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for your input. I was not aware of that library - it seems to work well.

Comment: @BoltClock To the extent that this is convenient/necessary (but as I said, it generally isn’t, for R), it should be provided *automatically*, *by the website UI*, not require non-obvious, manual work from the question asker. (Some other answers already suggested having a button next to a Markdown table that allows copying the data in various formats.)

Comment: @BoltClock  I agree -- that's exactly my suggested answer and should be straight-forward to implement.

Answer (score 5):

> There is a good explanation of why this is necessary...

Aside from word/acronym mismatch (weproducible?), it’s an explanation of things that could be more useful in getting a good answer, but that does not make any of them necessary as part of asking a question or getting a useful answer. It’s unlikely that someone is going to find that and read all the way through it and understand it before posting their first few questions. Even if they do, the very top answer on that post has a first bullet point saying ...

> share a minimal dataset

... which is exactly what the user did in the question used as your example and I think is the thing you are complaining about. It’s something that good questions about databases and data related things should have in them.

@Larnu is talking about the markdown formatting style for tables, not if the user should include tabular data.

> Personally I will avoid any questions where the data is formatted like this.

That’s your choice, but I can tell you it feels better and is a more positive experience all around to use an evaluation like "Can I help this person, even a little bit?" rather than "Did this person meet all of my syntax requirements in order to give them assistance?"

Comment: haha, this is exactly why I try to avoid StackOverflow as much as possible. It is not based on human values.

Comment: Speculations like "This code might work" are often discouraged in SE and usually do not help the OP. To have a formatting that helps the answerer (not just one answerer, but a vat majority of them) to recreate and code on top of it in their system. If you are annoyed by the number of "like", "might", "usually" and "vast majority" in this comment, you should realize the answer to bad formatted questions will be equally annoying.

Comment: @nightgaunt - i honestly do not see the relationship between what you are saying and what I said. Can you make the connection(s) for me?

Comment: @StingyJack With all due respect, I feel like you might have missed the point of my post - perhaps because you do not answer questions in R. They shared a minimal dataset, but it was not *reproducible*. This isn't about me demanding people 'meet all my syntax requirements', it's the difference between me spending 1 second to perfectly replicate their dataset into my console or 5 minutes manually typing it in, possibly screwing it up in the process (i.e. getting the column class wrong). That is why I don't do it, not because I too grumpy or lazy to bother.

Comment: A non reproducible problem or difficult to reproduce problem leads to speculations in answers. It ends up wasting time for both OP as well as the answerer. The comment was my lame attempt to make that point. @user438383 mentioned why it leads to speculations or wrong answers in his comment.

Comment: @nightgaunt - i get what you mean now. ty for explaining.

Comment: @user438383 - Avoid false or illogical assertions at the beginning of an idea and there will be less chance of a misunderstanding. Maybe using dput isnt as simple as you think (several hundred questions for `[r] how use dput`). Have you asked people who use tabular to use dput instead? Do they even know how to do that? I RTM for that command and its not clear how to export test data into an expression using dput.  Tables may suck for answering (not disagreeing) but it may be the best the asker can do. 5 minutes of donated time is still a good thing whether you can help 100 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally users would post example input in an immediately loadable format, but I don't think tables are so awful, given you can easily copy-paste **the markdown used to generate them** (i.e. a pipe-delimited format) by clicking on the source link of a post (alternatively, clicking 'edit' to view the raw markdown).

e.g. you can easily load the table in your example post with `read.table()`. You need only remove the first line `---|----|---` (and possibly the first and last columns if leading/trailing pipes were used):

```r
table_str = "| siteID | BirdA | BirdB | BirdC | elevation |
|:-------|:-----:|:-----:|:-----:|:---------:|
|1       | 3     |  2    |   0   |    275    |
|2       | 1     |  5    |   1   |    550    |
|3       | 0     |  0    |   3   |    850    |
|4       | 4     |  3    |   2   |    322    |"

df = read.table(text=table_str, header=TRUE, sep="|")[-1,]

# Remove leading/trailing pipe cols if used in markdown
df = within(df, rm(X, X.1))
```

Comment: Sure but at this point we’re quite far from “easily copy-paste”. It requires (completely unnecessary) cleanup work, *and* the inclusion of the extra row forces the column types to be strings.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think you've misread my answer. I said "you can easily copy-paste the markdown used to generate" the table, as opposed to manually typing each cell like the OP said. It's unnecessary if the user doesn't put leading/trailing pipes (they're not required for common-mark), and so you need no cleanup if they don't do that. But in this example the user did.

Answer (score 0):

I want to optimise for the lurker, the person who is just here to read the question and the answer. In my mind, tables are great for those reading the posts. I like tables.

Comment: "tables are great for those reading the posts" Tables are awful for answering these questions. They take almost as much effort to convert to executable code as an image and there are methods of formatting executable code that are just as easy to read as tables for the casual reader and make it much, much easier for the answerer.

Comment: @MT0 for SQL they don't take much effort to convert - as long as SQL Fiddle is around. I pasted the table from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66931471/73226) into the "Text to DDL" dialogue and it generates `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for it fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6e5G.png

Comment: @MartinSmith SQL Fiddle only supports Oracle 11g; there were major enhancements in Oracle 12c which SQL Fiddle does not support (and often SQL Fiddle's Oracle database is not available). DB<>Fiddle and Oracle's LiveSQL do not automatically convert data to tables so saying that one tool supports it when that tool does not support the queries that you need to debug is not helpful and, even if it does work, it then puts the burden onto an external tool.

Comment: For R, formatted tables won't help the lurker unless they want to know about importing from/exporting to a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Elin That’s just wrong. Tables help lurkers because they are more readable, and thus make it immediately clear how the tabular data looks like and whether a given question applies to the lurker’s own problem. In fact, this is patently obvious to anybody who has ever read R questions. Claiming the opposite is frankly … bizarre.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Not if they are using R.  The only time data in R looks like that when _reading it in_ is if it is from a spreadsheet.   `dput` outputs are nicely aligned and just as easy to read.

Comment: @Elin “`dput` outputs are nicely aligned and just as easy to read.” — That’s nonsense, where are you getting this from?! `dput` does *not* aligned its output at all, and it’s definitely not as easy to read as a table.

Comment: Sorry, followed by a print  they print nicely and can be included.

Comment: @Elin I repeat, that’s simply false (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1968)). You’re spreading misinformation.

Answer (score -4):

> I was wondering if there would be a way to discourage users to share their data in this format for particular questions

Yes, there is. Downvote and explain why you downvoted.

Comment: I think downvoting for providing a valid and sensible question, using the tools available, is a bad idea.