# Darker CSS for visited links on SO meta?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, formatting

Depending on the context, previously visited links on Stack Overflow Meta can be quite tricky to spot.

Example - there are four in the image below - they're somewhat tricky to spot (for me, at least):

> [image]

(image from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406525/discouraging-questioners-from-posting-data-in-table-form-for-questions-on-r-sql))

Is it possible to make them a little darker so they stand out more?

Comment: There are only 3 links in the image.  Part of the problem is the anti-pattern of linking the word "here" instead of the text describing what is at the link.  For example, the second link should be written as "[Here is a good explanation of why this is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)" which naturally makes it much more visible.